# What does :& argument mean?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand the `:&` argument for the inject method in this example:

```
[1, 2].map do |id|
  my_custom_method(MyModel.find(id))
end).inject(:&).map(&:category).uniq.compact.sort
```

`:+` makes sense to me:

```
[1, 2, 3].inject(:+)
```

is the same as:

```
[1, 2, 3].inject { |sum, number| sum + number }
```

What does `:&` mean, as in the example above?

Comment: "What does `:&` mean, as in the example above?" Well, do you see the relationship between `[...].inject(:+)` and `x + y`? Do you understand what `x & y` does? Just fill in the analogy.

Comment: `arr.inject(:&)` gives the same result as `arr.inject { |sum, number| sum & number }`. [Integer#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-26) computes a bit-wise intersection. Suppose `arr = [33,48]`. As `33.to_s(2) #=> "100001"` and `48.to_s(2) #=> "110000"`, it should not be surprising that `[33,48].inject { |sum, number| sum & number }.to_s(2) #=> "100000"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

> If you specify a symbol instead, then each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo

So `&` is just [Integer#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-26) method

> Bitwise AND; each bit in the result is 1 if both corresponding bits in self and other are 1, 0 otherwise

```
[7, 5].inject(:&) # => 5
```

It's the same as

```
7 & 5 # => 5
```

And how it works

```
7.to_s(2) # => "111"
5.to_s(2) # => "101"
```

```
7: 1 1 1
   & & &
5: 1 0 1
--------
5: 1 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it makes sense, but I'm not understanding why would we need to run the bitwise operator for my example.

Comment: It's probably not being done on Integers, but on some kind of a dataset. It's probably adding the datasets together, that's my guess.

Comment: @hmdne Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.  I think since the result is an array I think it finding the intersection between the two arrays. The result of `[1,2,3]` & `[3,4,5]` is simply `[3]`.

Comment: _"So `&` is just `Integer#&` method"_ – only if the collection contains integers. From the OP's code it isn't clear what kind of objects `my_custom_method` returns, but the result of `inject(:&)` apparently responds to `map` which would rule out integers. Arrays seem reasonable.

Comment: @Stefan that's right. We don't know what `my_custom_method` returns